# rejected due to the sending MTA's poor reputation

Tags: email

I know there are many questions with the same concern, but can't find one that has the same issue with mine.

No bounceback message received when we send an email and I am seeing the error below when I check my mail queue.

Your access to this mail system has been rejected due to the sending MTA's poor reputation. If you believe that this failure is in error, please contact the intended recipient via alternate means.

My IP is address is not blacklisted, the sendbase reputation score is neutral and I have a valid ptr record. Also, no IP on /24 block has a poor reputation.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

-Cherry

Answer (score 2):

did you check a lot of rbls or just one?

try some multi-checks:

- http://www.anti-abuse.org/multi-rbl-check/
- http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx/
- http://www.dnsbl.info/
- http://multirbl.valli.org/

the response does not suggest it but it's always good to make sure you have:

- non generic, valid, forward-resolving rev-dns for your server's ip
- valid SPF record for the domain you're putting in the FROM: field

Comment: the other side can still use some more obscure rbl. or might be black-listing whole countries. you [will] never know.

Comment: I used all the rbls checkers you provided except from the http://multirbl.valli.org/. My IP is blacklisted in APEWS (I guess this is fine) and abuse.rfc-ignorant.org (this link isn't working, not sure how to removed there). 

Btw, there are only 2 domains rejecting my emails, for now.

Comment: There will be more domains blocking you later if you don't find and fix the problem now.

Comment: Yeah, even yahoo blocked my domain. :( Got the following error.

54 Message
    not allowed - [PH01] Email not accepted for policy reasons.  Please visit
    http://postmaster.yahoo.com/errors/postmaster-27.html [120] (in reply to
    end of DATA command)

I'm not sure how to remove my domain to rfc-ignorant.org list. I do have an abuse email address.